# How to create a user session while running Junit test case

Tags: java, oracle, session, junit, junit4

I have written some test cases in Junit. Now while running these test cases I am getting an error because the values needed for some of the attributes are to be provided from a user session , like the user name. So how is it possible to create a user session while running the Junit test case and provide the session values for these attributes.
I have to enter these attributes into an Oracle database.
Thanks,
Nigel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some mock implementations for HTTP testing - for example Spring has `org.springframework.mock` package including classes like `MockHttpSession`.

Using mocks you can create a test instance and pre-populate it with test values so to your code it looks like a real session.

Answer (score 0):

Create a properties file where you define the username and password.
Write a custom method to getUserSessionObject using the username and password(if needed because you can select the user details from the database using the username itself) from the properties file.
Set the userSessionVariables from the getUserSessionObject.
Call this function whenever the commit is called.